# Build SQL query which returns dates according to "start / stop" states and dates of a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to create a SQL query which selects all dates from the table `DJU` according to the start / stop status of my second table `HEATING`

`DJU Table` :

[image: DJU]

`HEATING Table` :

[image: HEATING]

The field `HEATING_STATE` is the state of my heating system (1 if started, 0 if stopped) and `HEATING_DATE` is the date of the started / stopped states.

I want to get all `DJU_DATE` when the `HEATING_STATE` is to `1` (started) according to the `HEATING_DATE`.

So in this example, I want to get the following `DJU_DATE` results :

```
2019-11-12
2019-11-13
2019-11-14
2019-11-17
2019-11-18
2019-11-19
2019-11-20
2019-11-21
2019-11-22
2019-11-23
2019-11-24
```

I tried the query below, but it didn't give the right result.

```
select      DJU_DATE
from        DJU
where       exists (
                            select  HEATING_DATE
                            from    HEATING
                            where   (
                                                DJU.DJU_DATE >= HEATING.HEATING_DATE
                                        and     HEATING.HEATING_STATE = 1
                                    )
                            and     (
                                                DJU.DJU_DATE < HEATING.HEATING_DATE 
                                        and     HEATING.HEATING_STATE = 0
                                    )
                        )
group by    DJU_DATE
order by    DJU_DATE asc
```

Can you help me build a query that produces the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dju.dju_date FROM dju 
WHERE 1 = (
    SELECT heating.heating_state 
    FROM heating
    WHERE heating.heating_date <= dju.dju_date 
    ORDER BY heating.heating_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY dju.dju_date
;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail for a dju_date of 2019-11-16 based upon the sample data provided?

Comment: Good question. 2019-11-16 will be properly excluded from the final result set because the subquery that retrieves the most recent heating_state will find the heating row for 2019-11-15, which has a heating state of 0 and not 1.

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tested your query with the data? I don't have a MySQL database to do so.

Comment: Yes, it's here at this MySQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd505/3

Comment: Big thanks for your answer, it working well and it's really easy query to do that, I haven't think to did the query in this way

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `BETWEEN`. Here is an example that should work.

```
SELECT dju.dju_date
FROM   dju,
       (SELECT h1.heating_date h1_date,
               (SELECT MIN(h0.heating_date)
                FROM   heating h0
                WHERE  h0.heating_date >= h1.heating_date
                AND    h0.heating_state = 0) h0_date
        FROM   heating h1
        WHERE  heating_state = 1 ) h
WHERE  dju.dju_date BETWEEN h.h1_date AND h.h0_date-1
ORDER BY dju.dju_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have choose the other answer because of the easy way, but I understand better your way to did the query and it's working well too !